# Syntax issue with case expression inside scalar function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Having trouble creating a scalar function inside MS SQL 2005. Any suggestions would be appreciated. The title1_type field should be set according to the case statement. The sku is passed which should determine the type base on the case statement.

```
create FUNCTION [dbo].[gettitle1_type] (@sku varchar(50))  
RETURNS varchar(50) AS  
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @title1_type varchar(50)
    DECLARE @title1 varchar(50)
    select @title1_type = case @title1
        when @title1 like '%SMALL%' then 'size'
        when @title1 like '%large%' then 'size'
        when @title1  like '%pink%' then 'color'
        when @title1  like '%red%' then 'color'
        when @title1  like '%brunette%' then 'color'
        else ''
    END;
    where sku = @sku

    RETURN isnull(@title1_type,'')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to

1. Get rid of the semi colon after `END;` This is not the end of the statement. Optionally you could put one after `where sku = @sku` though.
2. Don't use `case @title1`, use `Case` instead. You are mingling the [2 forms of the `CASE` expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx).
3. Add a final `END` to finish the function definition.
4. Either remove the `WHERE` or add a `FROM`
5. (Optional and dependant on 4) It is best practice to put `WITH SCHEMABINDING` on scalar UDFs that do not do data access. This can help performance in some cases.

Giving the below

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[gettitle1_type] (@sku VARCHAR(50))  
RETURNS VARCHAR(50) 
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS  
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @title1_type VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @title1 VARCHAR(50) /*This is never assigned to ?!*/

    SELECT @title1_type = CASE 
        WHEN @title1 LIKE '%SMALL%' THEN 'size'
        WHEN @title1 LIKE '%large%' THEN 'size'
        WHEN @title1  LIKE '%pink%' THEN 'color'
        WHEN @title1  LIKE '%red%' THEN 'color'
        WHEN @title1  LIKE '%brunette%' THEN 'color'
        ELSE ''
    END
    /*
    FROM xyz
    WHERE sku = @sku;*/

    RETURN ISNULL(@title1_type,'')
END
```

Comment: What objects depend on this scalar function ?

Comment: @BogdanSahlean - Are you asking me? I've no idea!

Comment: @MartinSmith - I rephrase: what objects are used by this function ? What are the advantages if I use ”with schemabinding” within a function that doesn't depends on others objects (table, other functions, etc.)?

Comment: @BogdanSahlean - It can prevent unnecessary spools being added to the plan in some cases [as illustrated here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlprogrammability/archive/2006/05/12/596424.aspx)